# ros workspace on an ntfs file system?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can your ros_workspace folder be located on an NTFS file system?

I'm using ros electric and a wubi install of ubuntu 11.10.

I've added a new hard drive that I want both windows and linux to access, and I'd like to move my ros_workspace folder to the new hard drive. Unfortunately when I run my nodes from the new environment I get:

$ rosrun loader_testing boomPosCnt

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named boomPosCnt below /media/may2013/ros_workspace/loader_testing
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /media/may2013/ros_workspace/loader_testing/bin/boomPosCnt

When I switch the environment back to the old workspace in my home folder (ext4 file system) the nodes run fine. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63950/ros-workspace-on-an-ntfs-file-system?/) by [4praytor](https://answers.ros.org/users/5019/4praytor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [4praytor](https://answers.ros.org/users/5019/4praytor/) on 2013-05-30**:
Thanks mirzashah your idea worked!

I wound up following this post to remount the drive: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1604251

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a duplicate of another question:
http://answers.ros.org/question/63952/ros-workspace-file-system/

---

Originally posted by [mirzashah](https://answers.ros.org/users/3576/mirzashah/) with karma: 1209 on 2013-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1